# Consistency of restricted forms of Martin's Axiom with the negation of the Continuum Hypothesis

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Consider $\mathsf{MA}(S)$, the forcing axiom for all ccc posets which preserve a Souslin tree $S$.  is $\lnot \mathsf{CH}$ consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}+\mathsf{MA}(S)$? Does there exist a model for $\mathsf{ZFC}+\mathsf{MA}_{\omega_1}(S)[S]+\lnot \mathsf{CH}$?

Comment: How is Cohen forcing "essentially the same" as adding a Suslin tree? This is like saying that any finite support iteration of nontrivial forcings of infinite length is "essentially the same" as Cohen forcing, just because a Cohen real is added at limit steps of countable cofinality.

Comment: (My point is that the part you wrote "too vague" about is really "too wrong".)

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  Sorry.  having removed what was "too wrong", can you answer either of the two questions?

Comment: What's $MA(S)[S]$?

Comment: @Asaf: Usually, $\mathsf{MA}(S)[S]$ is a _façon de parler_ for the result of forcing with the Souslin tree $S$ over a model of $\mathsf{MA}(S)$. It's not really a well-defined axiom (and I believe the notation was introduced by Franklin Tall).

Comment: @Arthur: Danke.

Comment: @Asaf: Kein Problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, given a fixed Souslin tree $S$ here are models of $\mathsf{ZFC} + \mathsf{MA}(S) + \neg \mathsf{CH}$. Basically just take a regular cardinal $\theta > \aleph_1$ such that $2^\lambda \leq \theta$ for all $\lambda < \theta$ and proceed to force $\mathsf{MA} + \mathfrak{c} = \theta$ mostly as usual: a finite support iteration $\langle \mathbb{P}_\alpha , \dot{\mathbb{Q}}_\alpha \rangle_{\alpha \leq \theta}$ of length $\theta$ of all c.c.c. posets of cardinality ${<}\theta$; but skip those posets that don't preserve $S$.

- As Cohen forcing doesn't destroy any Souslin tree (and as the iteration doesn't collapse cardinals), in the extension we will have $\mathfrak{c} = \theta > \aleph_1$.
- By induction on $\beta \leq \theta$ we can show that $\mathbb{P}_\beta$ does not destroy $S$. For this note that since all our posets belong to the ground model, $\mathbb{P}_\beta \Vdash \check{S}\text{ is Souslin}$ iff $\mathbb{P}_\beta \times S$ is c.c.c. iff $S \Vdash \check{\mathbb{P}}_\beta\text{ is c.c.c.}$
- By repeating the standard argument, in the extension whenever $\mathbb{Q}$ is a c.c.c. poset of cardinality ${<}\mathfrak{c}$ which doesn't destroy $S$, and $\{ D_i : i < \lambda \}$ ($\lambda < \mathfrak{c}$) is a family of dense subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$, there is a $\{ D_i : i < \lambda \}$-generic filter for $\mathbb{Q}$.
- Basically repeating the standard argument showing that $\mathsf{MA}$ for c.c.c. posets of cardinality ${<}\mathfrak{c}$ implies the full $\mathsf{MA}$, we can show that $\mathsf{MA}(S)$ holds in the extension.

(Additionally, if you happen to have a supercompact cardinal laying around, you can get a model of $\mathsf{PFA}(S)$ using the same standard technique to get the consistency of $\mathsf{PFA}$ modulo that supercompact. It is a result of Tadatoshi Miyamoto that the countable support iteration of proper posets which do not destroy a fixed Souslin tree $S$ also doesn't destroy $S$.)

Comment: Thanks.  So in these models, are there any non-free Whitehead groups?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin: Sorry, but I am unable to say one way or the other as I'm quite ignorant of the proof of the independence of Whitehead's problem.